# When using jsonlite in R, how do I specify that only some of the entries are to be treated as arrays?

Tags: r, serialization, jsonlite

I have the following code:

```
# install.packages("jsonlite")
require("jsonlite")
x = list(
    test = "my_test",
    data = c(1, 2, 3)
)
toJSON(x)
```

This prints:

```
{"test":["my_test"],"data":[1,2,3]}
```

I was expecting:

```
{"test":"my_test","data":[1,2,3]}
```

I've tried using some of the parameters from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.5/topics/toJSON%2C%20fromJSON), but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 4):

The argument `auto_unbox=TRUE` did the trick:

> automatically unbox all atomic vectors of length 1. It is usually safer to avoid this and instead use the unbox function to unbox individual elements. An exception
>   is that objects of class AsIs (i.e. wrapped in I()) are not automatically unboxed. This is a way to mark single values as length-1 arrays.

I.e., the solution was `toJSON(x, auto_unbox=TRUE)`, which returns what I expected:

```
{"test":"my_test","data":[1,2,3]}
```